# use rename to change one number in complex filename

Tags: linux, perl, rename

Using Linux command line tools, we want to change file names of the following format:

```
SC1177.2.0002.2015.09.16.18.05.05.900577.177003720.IMA
```

We want to keep everything the same, except add 100 to the second number. So that filename would become:

```
SC1177.102.0002.2015.09.16.18.05.05.900577.177003720.IMA
```

Note that we can't just prefix "10" because another filename is:

```
SC1177.10.0032.2015.09.16.18.05.05.900577.177107276.IMA
```

Which should then become:

```
SC1177.110.0032.2015.09.16.18.05.05.900577.177107276.IMA
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use awk help with the rename.  For example, if the file name was in a variable `name`, you could change the name with:

```
newname=`awk -F. -v OFS=. '{$2+=100};1' <<<$name`
```

If you wanted to go further and rename all files starting with SC in a specific directory, you could do:

```
for name in SC*; do
    newname=`awk -F. -v OFS=. '{$2+=100};1' <<<$name`
    mv "$name" "$newname"
done
```

Comment: Thank you! Maybe doing something really dumb, but just typed that into ubuntu command line, and it just hung with ">" on last line. Can't get normal prompt back.

Comment: Had a typo...  Just fixed.

Comment: FYI - I only tested the first code block...  Hence the typo.

Comment: Fantastic! But we had to correct a typo. There is a $ after name on the third line that needs to be removed. Then it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oops!  Sorry - my typo fix added a typo.